# AWS Lambda read contents of file in zip uploaded as source code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have two files:

```
MyLambdaFunction.py

config.json
```

I zip those two together to create *MyLambdaFunction.zip*.  I then upload that through the AWS console to my lambda function.

The contents of *config.json* are various environmental variables.  I need a way to read the contents of the file each time the lambda function runs, and then use the data inside to set run time variables.

How do I get my Python Lambda function to read the contents of a file, *config.json*, that was uploaded in the zip file with the source code?

Comment: Not sure using that method, but you could absolutely move the config to S3 and read the file from there each time.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-lambda-config

Comment: @j-u-s-t-i-n agreed, and if I have to I will.  But it'd be really nice to just have it all zipped up in one file (MyLambdaFunction.zip) and upload that to the lambda function.  Eliminates the need for another S3 bucket and worrying about encryption there.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Figured it out with the push in the right direction from @helloV.

At the top of the python file put `import os`

Inside your function handler put the following:

```
configPath = os.environ['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] + "/config.json"
print("Looking for config.json at " + configPath)
configContents = open(configPath).read()
configJson = json.loads(configContents)
environment = configJson['environment']
print("Environment: " + environment)
```

That bit right there, line by line, does the following:

- Get the path where the config.json file is stored
- Print that path for viewing in CloudWatch logs
- Open the file stored at that path, read the contents
- Load the contents to a json object for easy navigating
- Grab the value of one of the variables stored in the json
- Print that for viewing in the CloudWatch logs

Here is what the config.json looks like:

```
{
    "environment":"dev"
}
```

**EDIT**
AWS lambda now supports use of environmental variables directly in the console UI.  So if your use case is the same as mine (i.e. for a config file) you no longer need a config file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. The file you uploaded can be accessed like:

```
import os

os.environ['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT']/config.json
```

Comment: Not working.  I added "import os" at the top of the python file.  Inside my function handler I have a line that says "environmentalConfig = os.environ['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT']/config.json". I then take the python file and the "config.json" file and zip them into one folder.  Upload that through the AWS Lambda console.  When it runs I get an error that says " "environmentalConfig = os.environ['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT']/config.json"]], "errorType": "NameError", "errorMessage": "global name 'config' is not defined"}"

Comment: @ScottDecker that's because the answer above is not correct syntax. It's a string concat so either do `os.environ['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] + '/config.json'` or use an f-string `f"{os.environ['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT']}/config.json"`...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I'd rather prefer judging the context of the running lambda to determine the config it should use, instead of uploading different zip files, which is difficult to maintain.

```
lambda_configs = {
    "function_name_1":{
    },
    "function_name_2":
   {
   }
}

config = lambda_configs[context.function_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just done it in python3.8 lambda with simple:

```
with open('./dir/file.whatever') as f:
```

And it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os


os.environ['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] + '/config.json'
```

or you can use formatting

```
f"{os.environ['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT']}/config.json"
```