# How do I read local files I packaged for my python 3.7 AWS lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-3.7

I've been trying to read a config json in my python AWS lambda package (I don't want to use the config in the console as I generate it with my code and it has odd properties), I zip it with everything else. I get the following error:

> {"errorMessage": "unknown url type: '/var/taskconstants/aws.json'", 
>   "errorType": "ValueError",   "stackTrace": [
>       "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py\", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n",
>       "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py\", line 171, in load_source\n    module = _load(spec)\n",
>       "  File \"\", line 696, in _load\n",
>       "  File \"\", line 677, in _load_unlocked\n",
>       "  File \"\", line 728, in exec_module\n",
>       "  File \"\", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
>       "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 13, in \n    AWS_JSON =
>   json.load(urllib.request.urlopen(os.getcwd()+\"constants/aws.json\"))\n",
>       "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py\", line 222, in urlopen\n    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)\n",
>       "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py\", line 510, in open\n    req = Request(fullurl, data)\n",
>       "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py\", line 328, in **init**\n    self.full_url = url\n",
>       "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py\", line 354, in full_url\n    self._parse()\n",
>       "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py\", line 383, in _parse\n    raise ValueError(\"unknown url type: %r\" %
>   self.full_url)\n"   ] }

I've tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39477729/aws-lambda-read-contents-of-file-in-zip-uploaded-as-source-code) and I got the above. The same thing happens with our without, it's just a different url to get an error on. Here's the relevant code

```
import json, random, boto3, os
import urllib.request
# Loading constants from aws json
AWS_JSON = json.load(urllib.request.urlopen(os.getcwd()+"constants/aws.json"))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It might be trivial, but the error says: unknown url type: '/var/taskconstants/aws.json whilst the code statement is json.load(urllib.request.urlopen(os.getcwd()+"constants/aws.json")). I am suspecting there is a missing '/' in your code before constants/aws.json

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I tried it but it didn't seem to fix the problem. I get the same error but with a new url with just the slash added. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: The application code unpacks to the directory `/var/task`

```
import json

with open('/var/task/constants/aws.json') as json_file:  
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I did try this before asking the question. I'm not sure if maybe it's something I did wrong elsewhere in my code but regardless I no longer use a constants file to read from but just paste the constants at the top with a bash script I use to package my lambda zip.