# How to connect EC2 using pysftp via AWS Lambda without .pem file or alternate to .pem file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-lambda, pysftp

I want to connect EC2 using pysftp library via AWS Lambda. I use below code to connect.

```
mysftp = pysftp.Connection(
    host=Constants.MY_HOST_NAME,
    username=Constants.MY_EC2_INSTANCE_USERNAME,
    private_key="./clientiot.pem",
    cnopts=cnopts,
)
```

I have put .pem file along with deployment package in AWS Lambda. See this image:

[image: pem file with deployment package]

Sometimes it works sometime not, like sometimes it says .pem file not found.

```
"[Errno 2] No such file or directory: './clientiot.pem'"
```

How to deal with it? Is there any way to access .pem file or data of .pem file securely.

I don't want .pem in AWS lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Paramiko directly (pysftp is just a thin wrapper around Paramiko), you can hard-code the key into your code and you won't have troubles with external resources:
[SSH/SCP through Paramiko with key in string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43958696/850848)

---

For referring to files in your Lambda task, see:
[AWS Lambda read contents of file in zip uploaded as source code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39477729/850848)

So this should work:

```py
private_key = os.environ['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] + "/clientiot.pem"
```

Answer (score 2):

PEM keys are a sensitive resource, so in this case I would suggest putting it into AWS Secrets Manager, and then grant Lambda permissions to retrieve that secret.

Here's [official tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/tutorials_basic.html#tutorial-basic-step1) on how to create secret.

Comment: How to use above secret to call pysftp.connection() method??

Comment: After you receive secret with boto3, you can save it as a file on `/tmp/` filesystem and use pysftp method as usual

Comment: /tmp/ folder deletes the file. I dont why .. it always create a file. I do check a files is exists or not but but it always not exists. Please help